# R ggplot2 use RStudio Chart Zoom settings to save Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Expanding the question by Jeremy K. in this question here [Set ggsave() aspect ratio to the ratio that RStudio's "Zoom" button gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400329/set-ggsave-aspect-ratio-to-the-ratio-that-rstudios-zoom-button-gives) specifically

I am using `ggsave()` to save plots from `ggplot()`.

In R-Studio, clicking the "Zoom" button automatically resizes most of my plots to have **quite aesthetic proportions**, whereas when I try to manually specify the size and aspect ratios, I get plots that **don't look as nice**.

The answer to the original question and the answers to the similar question [R: save figures in the zoomed window with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242595/r-save-figures-in-the-zoomed-window-with-command) both address screen size/resolution but nothing else. As the original question states the RStudio zoom has aesthetic **proportions** but using the screen width and height only sets the chart size and resolution. The titles, labels etc are all different (tiny in my case) in the saved image versus the original Rstudio zoomed image. Unfortunately using the 'inspect element' suggestion only gives the screen size and not any of the title and label sizes.

Is there a way that I can make `ggsave` (or any function) use <s>the same aspect ratio or size</s> **ALL** the same formats that R-Studio's "Zoom" button does?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm wondering the same!

Comment: Saving `ggplot` charts with high resolution for print or pdf is an art. I usually play around with `size` , aspect ratio (usually 6x4 in is a good starting point)