# How set the size of RStudio's Zoom pane?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, ragg

I store my plots with `ragg` with defined sizes and resolution.

```
  ragg::agg_png("Test.png",
    res = 320, width = 11, height = 15, units = "in")
```

If these plots are opened in the *Plot* Pane or in *Zoom*  the output is
totally different.

[image]

On the left is the `ragg` version and on the right is the *Zoom* version of
a plot.

I could find several posts which deal with the reverse problem of adjusting
the size of *png* to the size of the *Zoom* pane,

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308519/r-ggplot2-use-rstudio-chart-zoom-settings-to-save-chart)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400329/set-ggsave-aspect-ratio-to-the-ratio-that-rstudios-zoom-button-gives)

but I could not find anything which describes, if it is possible to open *Zoom*
with the same parameter as the I save a *png* with `ragg`.

Changing the graphics devices in **RStudio** did not help. Opening a new
graphics device

```
dev.new(width = 11, height = 15, unit ='in', noRStudioGD = T, res = 300)
```

did also not show any improvement.

Similar questions like [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/change-default-plot-viewer-zoom-size/37731)
were closed without answer.

Therefore I am not sure, if it is possible at all, to define the *Zoom* pane
size and resolution so that it fits to the `ragg`-saved version.

If that is the case I would like to learn how experienced `ggplot` developers
develop there plots stepwise with individual size and res settings.